# how to lock reading in mongodb with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, concurrency, cron

**prehistory**

I have a nodejs server which instances are running on multiple machines and every instance runs cron job once per day at the same time.

While one instance is running or has just finished its job, another instances should skip executing logic inside of jobs.

I've already had mongodb connection so I decided to save state of runned job and its time to DB and check/change it inside of every job's callback.
The document model I chose to save job state in collection is:

```
interface JobDao {
 _id: ObjectId;
 type: string;
 state: 'locked' | 'failed' | 'completed';
 updatedDate: DateISO;
}
```

I use package `"mongodb": "^3.6.3"` to make queries.

After some tries, I wonder if I can implement described bellow behavior or not. Also maybe somebody can suggest another solution to sync running jobs for multiple machines.

**So solution I try to implement and I ask for help with:**

- When cron starts, get job from DB.
- check state of job with such conditions:

  - if it's locked and not expired -> skip logic *(note: I use one hour expiration to prevent some unexpected issues when server was broken while running)*
  - if it's locked and expired -> change state of job to locked
  - if it's not locked but was updated till last 5 minutes -> change state of job to locked
- execute logic due to condition above
- "unlock" job (update job's state in document)

But here's the issue I met. As there's no concurrency. Between getting and updating the document in one machine, another machines can get or update stale document with not relevant data.

I've tried such solutions as:

- findOneAndUpdate
- tried to add aggregation *(here's the proplem to compare the exipration and it looks to be impossible).*
- trtransactions
- bulk

But nothing had worked. I start thinking to change DB but maybe somebody can say how to implement it with mongodb or can recomend some more suitable solution?

Comment: When you say reading from Mongodb? Why do you need locking as you are not updating/modifying the documents.  Have you checked [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/) ?

Comment: Yeah, I checked it.

The reason why I think I need to lock the document on read is such scenario:
while machine A executes find document, machine B also executes the same find of the same document. When machine A realices that it can continue running, it changes state of the document in DB but machine B has already got stale document before machine A changed state.

Comment: IT seems you might need to do FIndAndUpdate. In that case there is key `_v` you can use for the version change meaning modification on the particular document. Generally, these are atomic operations, so you might need to check the current and last version.  Mongoose might help you in this. Check [this](https://thecodebarbarian.com/whats-new-in-mongoose-5-10-optimistic-concurrency.html) link.

Comment: And I modify documents: When job gets that it can run the logic, it changes the field ```state``` of the document inside the DB's collection *Jobs*

Comment: I tried ```FindOneAndUpdate``` but there's an issue: I need to have field ```updatedAt``` which I get in the result of find operation to decide which value I wanna update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a small rest I decided to start from the scratch and I finally found a solution.
Here's my code example. It's not perfect, so I'm planning to refactore it, hovever, it works and solves my issue! Hope it'll help sb.

**Small description of its logic**

The "mediator" is the public method `scheduleJob`. Logic order:

- when we schedule job, it creates new document for the type in DB if it doesn't exist.
- unlocks job if it's stale (it's stale if has been locked more than for a half an hour). *Server can fall down while running job what cause infinite lock of job but checking stale job should help*
- next step is locking unlocked job, othervise, finish the logic. *It's possible when one instance finishes job just before next instance starts, so I added finishing of the job if the same job was running for last 5 minutes. It's important that such condition restricts frequency as jobs can't bet runned every 5 minutes but in my case it's suitable solution*

`CronJobDao` and `CronJobModel` are the same and represent the document in DB:

```
export interface CronJobDao {
  type: CronJobTypeEnum;
  isLocked: boolean;
  updatedAt: Date;
  completedAt: Date;
}
```

Service with `scheduleJob` method:

```
import { inject, injectable } from 'inversify';
import { Job, scheduleJob } from 'node-schedule';
import { CronJobTypeEnum } from '../core/enums/cron-job-type.enum';
import { CronJobRepository } from './cron-job.repository';


@injectable()
export class CronJobService {
  readonly halfHourMs = 30 * 60 * 1000;
  readonly fiveMinutesMs = 5 * 60 * 1000;

  constructor(
    @inject(CronJobRepository) private cronJobRepository: CronJobRepository,
  ) {}

  scheduleJob(type: CronJobTypeEnum, timeRule: string, callback: Function): Job {
    this.cronJobRepository.registerJob(type).then();

    return scheduleJob(
      type,
      timeRule,
      async () => {
        await this.unlockStaleJob(type);

        const lockedJob = await this.cronJobRepository.lockJob(type);

        if (!lockedJob) {
          console.warn('Job has already been locked');
          return;
        }

        if ((new Date().getTime() - lockedJob.completedAt?.getTime()) < this.fiveMinutesMs) {
          await this.cronJobRepository.unlockJob(type);
          console.warn('Job has recently been completed');
          return;
        }

        console.info('Job is locked');

        callback();

        await this.cronJobRepository.completeJob(type);
        console.info('Job is completed');
      },
    );
  }

  private async unlockStaleJob(type: CronJobTypeEnum): Promise<void> {
    const staleJob = await this.cronJobRepository.unlockIfTimeExpired(type, this.halfHourMs);

    if (!staleJob) {
      return;
    }

    console.warn('Has stale job: ', JSON.stringify(staleJob));
  }
}
```

Class for communication with DB:

```
import { inject, injectable } from 'inversify';
import { Db } from 'mongodb';
import { CronJobDao, mapCronJobDaoToModel } from '../core/daos/cron-job.dao';
import { CronJobTypeEnum } from '../core/enums/cron-job-type.enum';
import { CronJobModel } from '../core/models/cron-job.model';
import { AbstractRepository } from '../core/utils/abstract.repository';

@injectable()
export class CronJobRepository extends AbstractRepository<CronJobDao> {

  constructor(@inject(Db) db: Db) {
    super(db, 'cron_jobs');
  }

  async registerJob(type: CronJobTypeEnum) {
    const result = await this.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
      { type },
      {
        $setOnInsert: {
          type,
          isLocked: false,
          updatedAt: new Date(),
        },
      },
      { upsert: true, returnOriginal: false },
    );

    return result.value;
  }

  async unlockIfTimeExpired(type: CronJobTypeEnum, expiredFromMs: number): Promise<CronJobModel | null> {
    const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() - expiredFromMs);

    const result = await this.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        type,
        isLocked: true,
        updatedAt: { $lt: expirationDate },
      },
      {
        $set: {
          updatedAt: new Date(),
          isLocked: false,
        },
      });

    return result.value ? mapCronJobDaoToModel(result.value) : null;
  }

  async lockJob(type: CronJobTypeEnum) {
    return this.toggleJobLock(type, false);
  }

  async unlockJob(type: CronJobTypeEnum) {
    return this.toggleJobLock(type, true);
  }

  private async toggleJobLock(type: CronJobTypeEnum, stateForToggle: boolean): Promise<CronJobModel | null> {
    const result = await this.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        type,
        isLocked: stateForToggle,
      },
      {
        $set: {
          isLocked: !stateForToggle,
          updatedAt: new Date(),
        },
      },
    );

    return result.value ? mapCronJobDaoToModel(result.value) : null;
  }

  async completeJob(type: CronJobTypeEnum): Promise<CronJobModel | null> {
    const currentDate = new Date();

    const result = await this.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        type,
        isLocked: true,
      },
      {
        $set: {
          isLocked: false,
          updatedAt: currentDate,
          completedAt: currentDate,
        },
      },
    );

    return result.value ? mapCronJobDaoToModel(result.value) : null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend you to use some locking mechanism to sync between multiple services.
you can use basic mutex in case you want that only one service will write/read in your critical section.
im not sure exactly what you want in case one service trying to read while other service performing some changes (wait, skip or something else).
you can use some shared component such as redis to store the locking key.

Comment: Thaks for the answer. I'll try to clarify some things. I'm not about services but about the real machines (computers with different RAM, CPU, IP etc.). So nodejs service runs on many computers and every copy of the server on all computers schedule cron job. When some job managed to run first must be greedy and block all another not to allow them perform. As I know, in that case I can't use redis as it makes separate store for every machine and I'll need to sync all of them so it's the same issue I have))

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: @DenysKoval actually its not really matter, you can have some collection for the "keys" in your db